# How to play video from URL of any format

Tags: java, android

I want to play a video from URL in my Android application.

My code below:

```
 String url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQKdFFRqamg";           
 Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(url);
 videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
 videoView.start();
```

If the video has `.mp4` format it is working fine, but the following URL does not work: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQKdFFRqamg. It throws the below error:

> W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open http://www.youtube.com/watchv=QQKdFFRqamg:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider:
>   http://www.youtube.com/watchv=QQKdFFRqamg
>   05-05 16:45:50.298 28201-28201/it.sella.app.selacastrssfeed D/MediaPlayer: setDataSource IOException | SecurityException happend

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQKdFFRqamg is not a video. It is a Web page. `VideoView` can play videos. It cannot play Web pages.

Comment: yes, i can't play this in my viedoview. So i changed Video view to webview, now its working fine. Thanks CommonsWare

Answer (score 0):

Extract your video url and set in below example hop will be helpful

final VideoView videoView;

videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        videoView.setVideoPath("http://videocdn.bodybuilding.com/video/mp4/62000/62792m.mp4");
videoView.start();